# How to get parent path from filepath?

Tags: ruby, string, split, path

Let says I've this path:

```
path = "D:\Google Drive\Samples\Black Octopus Sound\Leviathan\Drums - Kicks\Lev_Kick_A_003.wav"
```

what's the smart and clean way to get the parent path from this `string/path`? i.e.:

```
D:\Google Drive\Samples\Black Octopus Sound\Leviathan\Drums - Kicks\
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of ways of doing it as a pure string, either via a regular expression or using split,pop,join.

```
path = "D:\\Google Drive\\Samples\\Black Octopus Sound\\Leviathan\\Drums - Kicks\\Lev_Kick_A_003.wav"
items = path.split("\\")
items.pop
result = items.join("\\")
puts result
> D:\Google Drive\Samples\Black Octopus Sound\Leviathan\Drums - Kicks
```

Note I've replaced "\" with "\\" in all cases to escape the slashes

Or in a one liner:

```
path.split("\\").reverse.drop(1).reverse.join("\\")
```

The best way is probably Pathname as per other answers, but if you can't use that then string manipulation should work.

Comment: you do realize, that your code is not valid Ruby code since you miss the closing `"` each time you write `"\"`? Even when you will correct the syntax, it still will not work

Comment: That's why I've said you may need to replace \ with \\ Edited to be more complete

Comment: yeap, now it is working :) +1. But now it is returning `"D:\\Google Drive\\Samples\\Black Octopus Sound\\Leviathan\\Drums - Kicks"` instead of `"D:\Google Drive\Samples\Black Octopus Sound\Leviathan\Drums - Kicks"`

Answer (score 2):

Use [Pathname](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html):

```
require 'pathname'

path = "D:\\Google Drive\\Samples/Drums - Kicks\\Lev_Kick_A_003.wav"
Pathname(path).parent
#=> #<Pathname:D:\Google Drive\Samples\Drums - Kicks>
```

Pathname correctly handles the specific file path syntax of the given operating system.

Comment: What makes you believe that I repeated your answer?